# Functions with a finite range are bijective?

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory, functions

Suppose we have a function $f : A \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \{ a_1 , \dots , a_n \} $.
So $\operatorname{range} f $ is finite. Can we conclude that $f$ is bijective? Or only can it be said that it is injective?

Comment: From the information that you’ve given $f$ might be not be either injective or surjective.

Comment: You can say neither.  If $f(A)$ equals the range, then it's surjective.  So for any map, $f: X\rightarrow Y$ you can can turn it into a surjection by saying $f: X\rightarrow f(X)$. Iow, any map is a surjection onto its image.

Comment: How about if we add $f$ to be nonnegative

Comment: That makes no  difference.

Comment: SO, Simple functions are not necessarily bijections ?

Comment: @Emprendedor You may be thinking of the statement that if the $|dom(f)| = |rng(f)| = n$ a finite integer then $f$ is bijective iff $f$ is injective iff $f$ is surjective.  This is a property of linear transformations on finite dimensional vector spaces as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. The only way for $f$ to be bijective is that  $A$ was a finite set with $n$ elements.

But $f$ is not bijective in general. For example, the graph of a function with a finite range could be something like this:

[image]

and if you use the [horizontal line test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_line_test) (red lines in the picture) you will see that the function of this example is not bijective, even if it has a finite range.